# Resize NTFS Volume LVM

Tags: ntfs, lvm, resize

This is my setup with a Harddrive of 1TB capacity and one lvm partition with the size of around 100GB on it. Within the LVM there is a NTFS drive containing Windows.

I'd like do resize the NTFS drive within the LVM to give Windows more space without damaging Windows.

lvs

```
  Couldn't find device with uuid KxVAIe-iJUu-LhXD-e5HR-WUR2-vRxl-GZj5tG.
  LV      VG               Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
  root    lukas-host       -wi-ao 103,18g                                      
  swap_1  lukas-host       -wi-ao  15,82g                                      
  win7x64 virtual-machines -wi-a- 100,00g
```

vgs

```
  Couldn't find device with uuid KxVAIe-iJUu-LhXD-e5HR-WUR2-vRxl-GZj5tG.
  VG               #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree  
  lukas-host         1   2   0 wz--n- 119,00g      0 
  virtual-machines   2   1   0 wz-pn- 234,37g 134,37g
```

pvs

```
  Couldn't find device with uuid KxVAIe-iJUu-LhXD-e5HR-WUR2-vRxl-GZj5tG.
  PV             VG               Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
  /dev/sda5      lukas-host       lvm2 a-   119,00g      0 
  /dev/sdb1      virtual-machines lvm2 a-   117,18g  17,18g
  unknown device virtual-machines lvm2 a-   117,18g 117,18g
```

fdisk -l /dev/sdb

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 Köpfe, 63 Sektoren/Spur, 121601 Zylinder, zusammen 1953525168 Sektoren
Einheiten = Sektoren von 1 × 512 = 512 Bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Festplattenidentifikation: 0x000831c1

   Gerät  boot.     Anfang        Ende     Blöcke   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048   245762047   122880000   83  Linux
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize logical volumes with the `lvresize` command.  Assuming you are using the LV as the virtual disk for a VM, windows will then think the drive has grown, and will have unpartitioned space on it.  You should then be able to use the Windows disk manager to expand the partition.

Comment: After I added an existing physical volume via `vgextend` to the volumegroup `lvresize`did the job and everything worked like a charm. Thank you a lot!